# Inserting strings into XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

I've created a .net program that essentially takes in a bunch of user options, then it passes these options into a 3rd party .dll through an xmlstring. My issue im having is taking my user data and inserting into into my XMLstring. 
Some example of my xml,

```
        XmlString.Append("      <Input>");
        XmlString.Append("        <ID>ReqInp_DrivenSpeed</ID>");
        XmlString.Append("        <Value>875</Value>");
        XmlString.Append("      </Input>");
```

This Xml is provided by the 3rd party, all i can change is the value, 875. 
I attempted to do it like this,

```
        XmlString.Append("      <Input>");
        XmlString.Append("        <ID>ReqInp_DrivenSpeed</ID>");
        XmlString.Append("        <Value>" + textbox1.SelectedText + "</Value>");
        XmlString.Append("      </Input>");
```

I thought this would work as its similar to what you can do with SQL, however, I'm getting no results back. Also the value entered into the textbox is 875, as its already a value accepted by the 3rd party app.

Edit- The issue was wrong type on my part, works correctly with `textBox1.Text`

Comment: Just to be sure, you are _selecting_ that value in the textbox, right? Because you're using `SelectedText` instead of `Text`. This means you have to _select_ (highlight in blue) the portion of text, for it to work.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault your right, thats why it wasnt working. Im getting data from comboboxes and using selectedValue, so i automaticly was using selectedtext instead of just text. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to add some formatted text within a builder
(I guess your `XmlString` object is a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) ?)

I would do like this :

```
XmlString.AppendFormat("        <Value>{0}</Value>", textbox1.SelectedText);
```

By the way, I see you use `Tostring()` on `SelectedText`.
Regarding [SelectedText documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectedtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
`SelectedText` is already a String (by the way, isn't it `ToString()` and not `Tostring()` ?)

Also, make sure the text is selected in your textbox ;)
If you just want the entire text typed in the TextBox try using :

```
XmlString.AppendFormat("        <Value>{0}</Value>", textbox1.Text);
```

Comment: i like where you going with this, however, im getting an error, "the best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(char*,int)' has some invalid arguements."

Comment: Use `AppendFormat` instead of `Append`